# How to open a partition handle to get its information on a dynamic disk?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, kernel32

For the purpose of logging in my application I need to get information about physical partitions on the disk, such as the info provided in [PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365448%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I have no problem doing it for "Basic disks" using the following method:

First let's assume the following drive configuration:

[image]

Then the following code works fine:

```
//Say, if I want to get info for partion 1 on disk 0 (or volume C:)
HANDLE hPart = ::CreateFile(L"\\\\?\\GLOBALROOT\\Device\\Harddisk0\\Partition1", 
    GENERIC_READ, 
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,  0, NULL);
if(hPart != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX pix = {0};
    DWORD bytesReturned = 0;
    if(::DeviceIoControl(hPart, IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX, NULL, 0, &pix, sizeof(pix), &bytesReturned, NULL))
    {
        //Got info OK
    }

    ::CloseHandle(hPart);
}
```

But if I try to retrieve the info on a "dynamic partition", say, disk 2, partition 1 (or 2nd half of spanned volume F:) and I try to use `"\\\\?\\GLOBALROOT\\Device\\Harddisk2\\Partition1"` in a call to `CreateFile`, it fails with error code 2, or `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

So the question is, how do I retrieve partition info on a dynamic disk?

Comment: Have you tried using WinObj to see what the actual device names are on your system?  Might give you a useful hint.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I wish WinObj had a search feature. I tried looking and even though I can find symlinks for (disk) devices, I don't see all partitions for them as I get from the snap-in like I showed above.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation:

[Basic and Dynamic Disks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785.aspx)

In particular, this section provides a hint:

> Detecting the Type of Disk
>
> There is no specific function to programmatically detect the type of disk a particular file or directory is located on. There is an indirect method.
>
> First, call `GetVolumePathName`. Then, call `CreateFile` to open the volume using the path. Next, use `IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS` with the volume handle to obtain the disk number and **use the disk number to construct the disk path, such as `"\\?\PhysicalDriveX"`. Finally, use `IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX` to obtain the partition list**, and check the `PartitionType` for each entry in the partition list.

Comment: Thanks. I found it too. Unfortunately that last statement about `IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX` is incorrect. Or I should say, it applies to "Basic disks" only. In case of a dynamic disk, like Disk 2 in my screenshot, it would appear as just one full-disk-size partition for a "Dynamic disk."

Comment: Yeah, the control code documentation confirms that: "only supported on dynamic disks that are boot or system disks, or have retained entries in the partition table."  Basically, it is telling you about the actual, underlying partitions on the physical disk - not about the higher-level dynamic volumes.

Comment: I think to get information on dynamic disks you might have to use [VDS or the Windows Storage Management API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb986750(v=vs.85).aspx) as appropriate.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I've never used VDS. You don't have a sample C code, do you?

Comment: No, I've never used it either.